# How do I show all completions immediately in completing-read?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

I'm writing an Emacs minor mode, and in it I use `completing-read` to let the user choose from a large set of search results.  They're different each time, so it's likely the user won't know what one they want without looking at the list.  For that reason, I'd like to show a temporary buffer with all the completions immediately instead of waiting for the user to hit Tab, but it's not obvious to me how to do so.  Is there a way, and what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get that by using `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` and adding `minibuffer-complete` to the setup hook, like so:

```
(setq tmp '("cat" "dog" "fish"))

(minibuffer-with-setup-hook 'minibuffer-complete
  (completing-read (concat "Pick one (" 
                           (mapconcat 'identity (all-completions "" tmp) " ") 
                           "): ") 
                   tmp))
```

Comment: This looks very, very promising.  I'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start. If your completion list is too big to fit in the mini-buffer, you'll have to open a temporary buffer to display all the options. Alternatively, just hitting tab on the empty prompt of completing-read will do that for you.

```
(setq tmp '("cat" "dog" "fish"))

(completing-read (concat "Pick one (" 
                         (mapconcat 'identity (all-completions "" tmp) " ") 
                         "): ") 
                 tmp)
```

Comment: What I meant is, "How do I show the temporary buffer with all the options immediately?"  I'll edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Ok. You should be able to do this with a keyboard macro, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles)**, and bind `icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag` around the call to `completing-read`:

```
(let ((icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag  t))
  (completing-read ...))
```